# Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages. jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I was working with Jupiter notebook but I entered a difficulty. Could you help me?
I have to use  `from scipy.special import j`. Even though I installed scipy lib, It could not run properly. After I searched, I used`%pip install scipy --upgrade`.
Then I got this message like:
"Requirement already satisfied". But at the end of the MSG, it said:

"Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."

I reseat kernel from toolbar thousand times, even I tried this code:

```
HTML("<script>Jupyter.notebook.kernel.restart()</script>")
```

Still, it said:
"Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."

Because I already reset the kernel many times and I do not know what else to do, I ran my import sentence again:
`from scipy.special import j`
but I see:
"ImportError: cannot import name 'j' from 'scipy.special'"

please help me if you can. Now I'm stuck!

Comment: Glad to know its not just for AWS SageMaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to create a New Environment (new_env), Then try this, sometimes the same name with multiple folders may cause this problem.

Step1: Create a New Environment.
Step2: Install the packages.
Step3: Definetely it will work.

Still, the Problem continues means, use it google collab!